# JavaScript - Paypal API, how do I change the shipping address?

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I've been trying to figure this out in the documentation, I found the address thing right here:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v2/#definition-address_portable

But I have no idea how to implement that change on my Paypal checkout button, there are no examples on how to implement it, does anyone know how?

This is what my Paypal sandbox checkout looks like right now (I skipped everything below `createOrder`)

```
<script>
   paypal.Buttons({

      createOrder: function(data, actions) {

         return actions.order.create({

            purchase_units: [{
               amount: {
                  value: '<?=$total?>'
               },
                  description: '<?=$description?>'
               }]
         });
      }

      // Skipped...

</script>
```

Comment: Usually the user selects the address themselves during checkout. When do you want to change the address? It's important to be very specific about when exactly in the process you need to change the address, as there are different answers depending on the exact time you need to change it, and why. Typically, you should not need to change it at all. Since you skipped significant code, perhaps what you are actually asking is "How do I _set_ a shipping address for a checkout". But why do you need to do that, and what happens when the user selects a different address after the checkout opens?

Comment: @PrestonPHX Currently on the website the user selects a shipping address then proceeds to pay using Paypal, so it doesn't matter if the user changes the address on Paypal checkout (it will be ignored), that's why we want to change the Paypal checkout shipping address, also you are right, my question actually is "How do I set a shipping address before opening the checkout", any idea on how to do that?

Comment: It *will* matter, and should NOT be ignored. That new address will be part of the PayPal transaction. Do you ship tangible goods? PayPal expects you to ship to the address that is part of the PayPal transaction. Whenever possible you should design a flow that offers the PayPal choice as early as possible and updates the chosen address for the order with what is selected in the PayPal checkout.

Comment: @PrestonPHX I had done it the way you are describing it, but there were changes on the website so it has to be done this way now, I seriously can't do anything about it, that's why I'm asking for help on how to change the checkout address, please help me if you know how to do that

Comment: You, or the people instituting this requirement, have not considered all the implications of what you are asking.  A solution that will lead to inconsistencies between your site's shipping address order record and the corresponding PayPal transaction's shipping address is NOT something you should be asking for.  I am not telling you how to do it because what you have described so far is a bad solution, and requires more thought.

Comment: This might be help: https://gist.github.com/adardesign/96e5805d6559e594bde46fa555367e69

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this structure of json

```
create_payment_json = {
                "intent": "sale",
                "payer": {
                    "payment_method": "paypal"
                },
                "transactions": [
                    {
                    "amount": {
                        "total": totalPlusTax.toFixed(2), //"30.11",
                        "currency": "USD",
                        "details": {
                            "subtotal": totalPrice, //"30.00",
                            "tax": "0.07",
                            "shipping": "0.03",
                            "handling_fee": "1.00",
                            "shipping_discount": "-1.00",
                            "insurance": "0.01"
                          }
                    },
                    "item_list": { 
                        items,
                        "shipping_address": {
                            "recipient_name": "Brian Robinson",
                            "line1": "4th Floor",
                            "line2": "Unit #34",
                            "city": "San Jose",
                            "state": "CA",
                            "phone": "12345678",
                            "postal_code": "95131",
                            "country_code": "US"
                          }
                    },
                    "description": "This is the payment description."
                }
                ],
                "redirect_urls": {
                    "return_url": "http://localhost:3000/execute",
                    "cancel_url": "http://localhost:3000/cancel"
                },
            };
```